# Events not triggering when using Send To (Mail Recipient)

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook VBA form, which (on the initialize event) loads various data into menus.
This works in normal usage, however, if you right click, send to (mail recipient) on a file or Send > Email in Word, when you click the button to load the form, the form displays but nothing in any events trigger either on the form load, or on the various click events.

Can anyone offer an explanation of why and how to work around the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [NewInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841.aspx) event of the Inspectors class.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook inspectors shown using Simple MAPI or mailto link do not fire inspector events. This was done on purpose.

Which particular event are you using?

Comment: Its the initialize event of the user form, I'm loading it from a quick access toolbar button in Outlook 2007  the form opens (and displays buttons etc), but no code that is under any of the events actually runs.  If I just open a new email, or forward an existing email, everything functions correctly.

Comment: Which events are supposed to run?